# Different type based on template type

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I have `::Class1` and `::Class2`, I'd like to create template function that gets either first or second one and then based on selected class use other classes defined in different namespace i.e. `NameSpace::Class1`, `NameSpace::Class2`. Is there way to do it in C++?

For example:

```
namespace NameSpace 
{ 
    class Class1 {}; class Class2 {}; 
} 

template <class T> // example Class1 or Class2 
void f(T object) { 
    NameSpace::T obj; // Something like this, but it doesn't work 
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample code? I'm not sure how you mean to use this.

Comment: namespace NameSpace {
    class Class1 {};
    class Class2 {};
}

template <class T> // example Class1 or Class2
void f(T object)
{
    NameSpace::T obj; // Something like this, but it doesn't work
}

Comment: But can I do this instantization in a generic way, without checking type (if else). What's with situation with many classes?

Comment: Try evaluating your code structure to find a different way of trying to accomplish whatever it is your template is doing.  C++ templates are meant to ignore the type information and allow for the user of the template to substitute type T for whatever type they want, as long as the symbols used in the template from type T exist, it should work as your intending.  ie.  Don't worry about class A or class B, worry about the implementation of your template, and only worry about A or B when you use the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  specialize a struct to map one type to another

```
template <typename T>
struct FromType {};

template <>
struct FromType<Class1>
{
    typedef ns::Class1 type;
}

template <>
struct FromType<Class2>
{
    typedef ns::Class2 type;
}
```

This can then be used in a template function by referring to the resulting type as

```
typename FromType<T>::type
```

Note that this will also give a compile error if you attempt to use a type other than Class1 or Class2.

Answer (score 3):

`NameSpace::T` doesn't work as `T` isn't the *name* `Class1` or `Class2`, it represents the type. Templates don't work on textual substitution like that.

You could provide a trait to translate between the type in the global namespace and that from `NameSpace`:

```
struct Class1{}; struct Class2 {};

namespace NameSpace 
{ 
    class Class1 {}; class Class2 {}; 

    template <typename T> struct translate;
    template<> struct translate<::Class1> {
        using type = Class1;   
    };
    template<> struct translate<::Class2> {
        using type = Class2;   
    };

    template <typename T>
    using translate_t = typename translate<T>::type;
}
```

You would use this like so:

```
template <class T>
void f(T object) { 
    using Translated = NameSpace::translate_t<T>;
    Translated obj;
}
```

Comment: Why the scope resolution operator on the specialized types?

Comment: @StoryTeller Because I put the trait in `NameSpace` to avoid polluting the global namespace, so `Class1` names `NameSpace::Class1` and `::Class1` names the one in the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just omnit the `NameSpace` in `NameSpace::T`. The namespace must be defined in the function `f` call. The following example compiles.

```
namespace NameSpace 
{ 
    class Class1 {}; class Class2 {}; 
} 

template <class T> // example Class1 or Class2 
void f(T object) { 
    T obj;
}

int main()
{
    NameSpace::Class1 x;
    f(x);
    return 0;
}
```